# RecordSet.RecordCount returns -1

Tags: vbscript, adodb, intersystems-cache

I know there are tons of questions on this and most of them say setting the cursor location fixes it (`resultSet.CursorLocation = adUseClient`).  This still returned -1.

I then found a post that said to try `RecordSet.MoveLast`, then get the `RecordCount`, then `MoveFirst` again before looping.  This still resulted in a -1.  I've also noted that my connection is a bit different than most of the ones I've found with this issue.  Here it is:

```
sDSN = "DSN=" & sDSN & ";UID=" & sUsername & ";PWD=" & sPassword & ";"
Set sConnect = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
sConnect.Open sDSN

sSQL = <big statement>

Set resultSet = sConnect.Execute(sSQL)
resultSet.CursorLocation = adUseClient
resultSet.MoveLast
WScript.Echo resultSet.RecordCount & " records found." 'Outputs -1
resultSet.MoveFirst
Do While Not resultSet.eof
   'do lots of stuff here
Loop
```

Comment: This may depend on your RDBMS as well. Some databases don't play nice with ADODB recordcounts. Furthermore, I was under the impression that the CursorType was more important for getting the recordcount back for the recordset. Primarily using CursorType's `adOpenKeyset` or `adOpenStatic` to avoid Dynamic and Forward only cursors.

Comment: added tags for RDBMS, thanks

Comment: I realized I was trying to set the cursor location on my connection object, not the resultset object.  I get no error now but it still returns -1

Answer (score 2):

Try using `Recordset.Open()` and supplying the recordset parameters instead of creating a speedy but limited "firehose" cursor (the type you get back from `Connection.Execute()`).

```
Const adOpenStatic = 3
Const adLockReadOnly = 1

Set resultSet = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
resultSet.Open sSQL, sConnect, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly

WScript.Echo resultSet.RecordCount
```

Comment: Unfortunately it's still -1.  Must be the RDBMS? (Intersystems Cache)

Comment: You may need to resort to SQL methods to return the row count as a column or output parameter (`row_number()`, `select count(*)`, `rank`, `@@rowcount`, etc.).